# How to get the type of the first parameter of a dependent function pointer template parameter in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits, template-argument-deduction

Current code:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, void (*D)(T *)>
std::pair<T *, void (*)(T *)> f(T * const t)
{
    // ...
    return std::make_pair(t, D); // need `T` and `D` here
}

void d(int *t);

void g()
{
    auto something = f<int, d>(new int {5});        
}
```

What I'd like:

```
#include <utility>

template </* fill here: only `D` */>
std::pair<T *, void (*)(T *)> f(T * const t)
{
    // ...
    return std::make_pair(t, D); // need `T` and `D` here
}

void d(int *t);

void g()
{
    auto something = f<d>(new int {5});        
}
```

Is this possible in C++11?

Comment: What about [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)?
Edit: after reading again, do you want to dynamically get a function's argument types?

Comment: No dynamically, at compile time. What I have in mind is something like `template <void (*D)(T *), typename T>`, and then you don't need to provide the second parameter because it's deduced from the type of the first parameter of `D`, but that doesn't work obviously.

Comment: @eepp What is `t` that you're passing as the function argument in `f<int, d>(t)`? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Anya Edited: the first example builds and works.

Comment: @eepp Ok, now it looks much better.

Comment: This can be easily achieved using the C++17 Non-Type Template Argument, but there doesn't seem to be a relatively easy way for C++11.